# How to setup SVN repo with existing environments

Tags: svn

I have a project I need to get working in SVN. There are development, staging, and production versions of code. I created a repository and loaded all the dev code and then made branches for staging and production. I synchronized the production Branch (local copy) with the code from the production server and tried to commit but got an error. It's been a while back, so I cannot recall the exact message but something about not being able to commit.

My question is, what would be the best way to set up the repository with the existing code bases and move forward with commits to dev. Merges from dev to staging and then staging to production?

More info:

By synchronizing, I mean copying code from the prod server to my local branch folder.

There are 3 network shares. I will call them \NS\dev, \NS\sandbox, \NS\prod.  All have different versions of files. I am trying to get into SVN.

I created a local repository and copied all files from \NS\dev to Local\App\trunk

I created a branch called prod.  I copied files from \NS\prod to Local\App\branches\prod and tried to commit.  I received an error: “copy operations are only supported at the branch level”.

How can I get the 3 versions into SVN so that I can begin making updates to dev and merge those changes up? Dev > sandbox, sandbox > prod.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is "synchronizing"? That term is not defined in subversion. What commands did you enter? Which errors did you receive? And - most importantly - what are you trying to accomplish? You mention you created branches and ask for the "best way" (whatever that may mean) to merge commits between them. Please [edit] your question and clarify. Thank you. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've updated my question to explain more of what I am trying to achieve. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: One more question: what did you do when you tried to commit and received the "copy operations only supported at the branch level" error?

Comment: I copied the files from the production server to the prod branch of the repository on my local machine and tried to commit any changes there.

Comment: I posted a kind of long-ish answer. I tried to go step by step. Did it help you? If not, please let me know which parts you didn't understand or have problems with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you already have three different versions (dev, sandbox and prod) of the same source code and want to put it under version control with subversion.

You chose to use subversion. Since your new to it, you should definitely read the [Red Bean Book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html).

You might think your decision for subversion over. These days, git is ubiquitous, well documented and you will quickly get answers for git on sites like this. Git is the tool of choice for new projects. However, there's nothing wrong with subversion, it's a good and reliable VCS. The biggest difference to git is that it is centralized. Subversion always has exactly one repository, usually it's running on a server and accessed via HTTP(S).

There's no such thing as a "local repository" (as you write in your question), there's only *the* repository. You might have created your repository on your local machine and that's okay as long as it's accessible by everyone on your team.

The conventional layout of a subversion repository is the following tree structure:

```
myproject
+ trunk     <-- a special branch for the development main line
+ branches  <-- for feature or release branches
| + a_feature
| + another_feature
| + release_for_customer_x
+ tags      <-- for releases and milestones
  + v1.0.0
  + some_demo
```

These are just names and conventions and you can basically choose any layout you want.

I will assume you want to have everything in your *dev* share in *trunk* and two branches *branches/sandbox* and *branches/prod*. This follows svn's [release branches](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.release) philosophy. Another way to is to insist the trunk to be stable and have [feature branches](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature). As I wrote, it's only names.

After you will have created the repo, checkout a *working copy* so you can work on your files. The example below shows how to make subversion track files and create branches that contain the different versions you already have.

```
# Checkout a working copy
svn checkout https://myserver/myproject/trunk myproject
# You will have an empty directory myproject as you did not yet commit anything
cd myproject
# -> Copy everything in \NS\dev into myproject
# Add the files so subversion will track them
svn add *
# Commit (upload) all your files to the repo
svn commit -m"Initial version of dev"
# Create a new branch "sandbox" from trunk
svn copy https://myserver/myproject/trunk https://myserver/myproject/branches/sandbox -m"Create sandbox branch"
# This short form is also possible
svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/sandbox -m"Create sandbox branch"
# Now make your working copy point to the newly created branch
svn switch ^/branches/sandbox
# -> Copy the files from \NS\sandbox into myproject, overwrite existing files
# Take a look at the differences
svn status
# Add the changed files
svn add *
# Commit to repo
svn commit -m"Initial version of sandbox"
# Repeat for prod:
svn copy ^/branches/sandbox ^/branches/prod -m"Create branch for prod"
svn switch ^/branches/prod
# -> Copy files from \NS\prod
svn add *
svn ci -m"Initial version of prod"
```

This way, you'll receive a repository tree with ancestral relationship between trunk and the branches. This will allow you to easily merge changes between the branches. It's easiest if you always switch your working copy to one of your branches. You can have different working copies on your drive. For instance, you could have three working copies in parallel like this:

```
svn co https://myserver/myproject/trunk dev
svn co https://myserver/myproject/branches/sandbox sandbox
svn co https://myserver/myproject/branches/prod prod
```

Or you have just one and use `svn switch` to access different branches.

Just make sure you always propagate changes using the `svn merge` command which will allow subversion to track what you merged from where and avoid conflicts. This is not possible if you merge in your editor or copy files around.
It works like this:

```
# Make sure working copy is on sandbox
svn switch ^/branches/sandbox
# Merge from dev to sandbox
svn merge ^/trunk .
# -> Resolve conflicts, if any
# Upload to repo
svn commit
```